# Nested for Loops - Only reading first "if" statement

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I have a nested for loop. it works, kinda. It only reads the first if statement as true. It ignores all possible true statments after that.

```
for(int i = 0; i < inGroups.length; i++)
{
    for(int g = 0; g < theGroups.length; g++)
    {
        if( inGroups[i].equals(theGroups[g]) )
        {
            gLV.setItemChecked(g, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not.  You've got a logic error.  Step through it with a debugger or add print statements.

Comment: Are you sure that inGroups is even matching with theGroups?

Comment: Clear your project first. Android projects in eclipse like to get corrupted/out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine.  As @Hot Licks mentioned, you should use a debugger and/or add print statements to see what's going on.

Couple of general comments about your code:

- You should make sure that your `Group` object or whatever is in your arrays has [implemented an `equals` method](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) otherwise it will always be false.
- Are you sure that `setItemChecked` can handle more than one value?  If set is called twice does it just overwrite the previous value?
- Your code is very inefficient (O(N^2)).  You could consider doing something like the following which is O(N).  It won't matter if the arrays are small of course.  If you use this method then you will need to [implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17).

  ```
  Set<Group> inGroupsSet = new HashSet<Group>();
  // load inGroups into a set
  for (Group group : inGroups)
      inGroupsSet.add(group);
  // look up each Group in theGroups in the set
  for (int g = 0; g < theGroups.length; g++)
      if (inGroupsSet.contains(theGroups[g]))
          gLV.setItemChecked(g, true);
  ```

Hope something here helps.

Comment: My debugger isn't throwing any errors, and my printouts aren't showing anything that's of any help (which is why I'm asking here). When I use a for loop to just setItemChecked it sets all of the items as checked fine. but when adding in the if statement it only works on the first item, and not on any of the following. I'll try some of your suggested ideas and see what I get. Thanks!

Comment: It's not about throwing errors from the debugger.  It's about putting a break point on the if statement and stepping through the execution of your program to understand what's going on.

Comment: Stepping though gave me no insight as to the problem. However, I did implement you're suggested code. It ran the same as I has the for loop. But when I swapped the Arrays, it checked multiple items in the list, just the wrong items because the iteration count was wrong. At this point I'm lost and can only think that there's something wrong with the Array I'm creating from a Cursor? I'll keep at it. I'm sure it'll end up being something disgustingly simple that I'm missing. Cheers.

Comment: Huh.  Bizarre.  Sorry I couldn't help more.  Taking your time with the debugger should be able to help.  Best of luck!

Comment: I got it. For whatever reason, it wasn't liking the way I was making a String[] from a Cursor. By creating a new String[c.getCount()] and by adding each string as theGroups[i] was causing the problem. No idea why. So I looked at how I was crating the inGroups String[] and copied it. I created a simple string while moving though the Cursor and and .split("\\, ") it. Don't ask why it liked that. It just did.